# How to add mutiple values to a key in a dictionary in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

```
M = int(input())
mydict = {}
for i in range (M):
    j,k = map(int, input().split())
    try:
        mydict[j].append(k)
    except KeyError :
        mydict[j] = k
print(mydict)
```

When I run the code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "source_file.py", line 7, in <module>
    mydict[j].append(k)
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'append'
```

Comment: Be sure that the value in the dict is of type list, and not 'int'. Only to a list can you append values

Comment: Can you share some sample input and expected output. Not sure what you are trying to achieve with the code.

Comment: This line after `KeyError` should be `mydict[j] = [k]`, so that the value is always a list to which you can append values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you are encountering is that the value of the key is initialised as an `int (k)` instead of a `list ([k])`. When you try to call `.append` on an `int` you get an `AttributeError`.

The pythonic way to initialise a key with a default value is to use either `dict.setdefault` or use a `defaultdict` so that your value type is initialised as a list when a new key is added.

Using a `defaultdict` with `default_factory=list` auto-creates a new list each time a key is added to the `dict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

M = int(input())
mydict = defaultdict(list)    # passing list as the default type

for i in range (M):
    j,k = map(int, input().split())
    mydict[j].append(k)
print(mydict)
```

Alternatively, you can use `dict.setdefault`:

```
M = int(input())
mydict = {}

for i in range (M):
    j,k = map(int, input().split())
    mydict.setdefault(j, []).append(k)   # using setdefault to initialise as a list
print(mydict)
```

Finally, if you still prefer the use of the `except` block, change line 8 in the original to `mydict[j] = [k]`

edit: typo